# How to prevent a user from entering a invalid answer

Tags: java

I have tried to stop the user from entering anything besides yes or no however when they do it just keeps on saying error try again forever.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println
            ("Would you like to add a Reciept. Yes or No");
    Scanner target = new Scanner(System.in);
    String TempAnswer;
    TempAnswer = target.nextLine();
    Boolean flag = true;
    while (flag == true) {
        if ("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(TempAnswer)) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
            flag = false;
        } else if ("no".equalsIgnoreCase(TempAnswer)) {
            System.out.println("No");
            flag = false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error Enter Again!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As much I know, you can't do it using console input.

Comment: by creating a dropdown only containing correct answers

Comment: `while (flag)` This is enough

Comment: Please respect the Java conventions. Variable names start with lowercase.

Comment: You should be able to follow the flow of the program and see the logic. If you entered an incorrect anser, you'll go to the else clause, print "Error enter again!" then start your loop over. Which will cause you to go to the else clause, print ... You need to *get user input again.*

Comment: few things you need to change in order to run this program correctly. 
this is your code you can check and run and learn.
https://onlinegdb.com/S1lWFF-MBw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never re-assigning the input value to your `TempAnswer` variable in the while loop and loop runs infinitely, as you never give the chance to the boolean value to be changed, based on user's input.

Few side-notes:

1. Use [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) and define your member variable identifiers with *camelCase*, not with *PascalCase*;
2. Do not introduce redundant code. Use `while(true)` instead of defining boolean variable `flag` and using it as the condition; correspondingly, use `break;` instead of setting `flag` to false.

Eventually, I would have rewritten your code as follows:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Would you like to add a Reciept. Yes or No");
    Scanner target = new Scanner(System.in);
    String tempAnswer = "";
    while (true) {
        if ("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(tempAnswer)) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
            break;
        } else if ("no".equalsIgnoreCase(tempAnswer)) {
            System.out.println("No");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error Enter Again!!");
            tempAnswer = target.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the superfluous calls and make sure that you read the answer in the loop. If you don't do that, you'll indefinitely loop because you're not changing the loop-condition.

Use break to break the loop instead of using flags for such small scope.

Also, don't use `Boolean`, use `boolean` instead. You will probably never have to use `Boolean`, so don't use it.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Would you like to add a Reciept. Yes or No");
    Scanner target = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        String tempAnswer = target.nextLine();
        if ("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(tempAnswer)) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
            break;
        }
        if ("no".equalsIgnoreCase(tempAnswer)) {
            System.out.println("No");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Error Enter Again!!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to break the loop when the correct answer is typed

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println
        ("Would you like to add a Reciept. Yes or No");
    Scanner target = new Scanner(System.in);
    String TempAnswer;
    TempAnswer = target.nextLine();
    while (True) {
        if ("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(TempAnswer)) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
            break;
        } else if ("no".equalsIgnoreCase(TempAnswer)) {
            System.out.println("No");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error Enter Again!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got the same problem op does.

Comment: ..and the `True` is not defined in Java SE.